Error in create the react native app with npx
I'm trying to create a react native app with the command npx react-native init MyTabletApp --template react-native-template-typescript but I got this error attached. How to create an rn app that starts with all folders and files created?  enter image description here
I'm developing in windows desktop
I tried cleaning the solution, removed the global cli installation and updated the node version, I'm using 10.9.0

If you want to create a new project with latest version you can try out these commands:
npx react-native@latest init MyTabletApp

OR
npx @react-native-community/cli init MyTabletApp

and you can refer to following link for more detail:
https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/init.md

npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init MyProject --version latest

Solution that I have discovered:

Create project from template this way :
npx react-native@latest init myawesomeproject --version 0.74.5 --pm npm --install-pods false 



Example : Choose the RN version of your choice.

When project is created, install pods the way you usually do it, for example: cd ios && arch -x86_64 pod install for mac with m1 CPU and cd ios && pod install for mac with intel based processor.


I had the same problem, I solved it just changing the version of react-native. It seems that the last one brings problems or something.
npx react-native init NameOfTheApp --version 0.74.1

I hope it will help you :)
